# Javascript - replacing a word using regexp only if there's a space around it

Tags: javascript, regex

A cut down version of my code sort of looks like this:

```
string="test test testtest testtest test";
replacer="test";
string=string.replace(new RegExp(' '+replacer+' ','gi')," REPLACED ");
```

Now, I want to replace a word only if there's a space surrounding it, The code actually works fine but I'm just wondering why the one below which would be better in my case doesn't work.

```
RegExp('\s'+replacer+'\s','gi')
```

Comment: @Dean: welcome to SO! It's polite to accept the most helpful answer by clicking the big checkmark to the left of it. Looks like @Breton's is the winner judging from your comment on it.

Comment: So, in your example, only the second "test" should be replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
RegExp('\\s'+replacer+'\\s','gi')
```

Comment: Awesome, RegExp('\\s'+replacer+'\\s','gi') worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Your example will replace tabs with spaces.

You probably want this:

```
string=string.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+replacer+'\\b','gi'),"REPLACED");
```

Or, if you really want *only* whitespace to separate words, then you could use something like this:

```
string=string.replace(new RegExp('(\\s)'+replacer+'(\\s)','gi'),"$1REPLACED$2");
```

Comment: @Jeremy, The OP said he wants to match words surrounded by whitespace; your regex will also match the `test` in `#test&`.

Comment: Thank you, Alan.  I guess if the OP wants to keep the same whitespace he'll need to capture it and use backrerefences in the replace text.  I'll update my example.

Comment: this is exactly what I'm doing, only there could be punctuation after the word so I am using \\W instead of \\s. Does that make sense?

string=string.replace(new RegExp('(\\W)'+replacer+'(\\W)','gi'),"$1REPLACED$2");

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many thing but no regex pattern worked perfectly.

My problem was I had to replace `"it"` with `<product_name>` in sentence.

For example,"what is use of it" => "what is use of `<product_name>`"

But in the words like acidity,regex pattern changes it to "acid`<product_name>`y" which is wrong.

I came up with one solution which solved my problem and would like to share it with you all.

```
var b=[];
var sent="what is use of it";
sent.split(" ").forEach((x) => {if(x=='it'){x=<product_name>;}b.push(x)});
sent=b.join(" ");
```